# Spring Security - GrantedAuthoritiesMapper changes not persisting

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm using the Active Directory implementation of Spring Security.  I've created a custom GrantedAuthoritiesMapper to map the AD roles to those of my application.  The changes to the Authorities, though, don't seem to take.

My config:

```
<b:bean id="grantedAuthoritiesMappers"
    class="com.xxx.TestAuthoritiesMapper"/>

<b:bean id="adAuthenticationProvider"
    class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider">
    <b:constructor-arg value="MYDOMAIN" />
    <b:constructor-arg value="ldap://192.168.2.4/" />
    <b:property name="authoritiesMapper" ref="grantedAuthoritiesMappers"></b:property>
</b:bean>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider ref="adAuthenticationProvider" />
</authentication-manager>
```

Code for the mapper:

```
public class TestAuthoritiesMapper implements GrantedAuthoritiesMapper {

    private static Logger logger = Logger
            .getLogger(GrantedAuthoritiesMapper.class.toString());

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> mapAuthorities(
            Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {

        logger.info("Coming in :" + authorities);

        Set newAuths = new HashSet();
        newAuths.addAll(authorities);
        newAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("Custom Role"));

        logger.info("Coming out :" + newAuths);

        return newAuths;

    }
}
```

Here I can see my augmented list of authorities.  Later, when I run:

```
    Object principal = this.getSecurityContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    UserDetails ud = (UserDetails) principal;
    log.info("Final auths:" + ud.getAuthorities());
```

I see only the original auths without the extra that I've added.

When I run through a debugger my modified auths are there all the way until Spring publishes the successful Authentication object.  Somewhere between the event being fired and my security context, the changes are lost.

Comment: Have you set authentication like `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication()` along with set of `GrandedAuthority` before on authenticate?

Comment: I'd expect the ActiveDirectory Auth Mgr to set this, no?

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by creating a custom class

I was able to get the user by overriding the method `mapUserFromContext` and updated its authorities.
Hope this helps.

```
public class CustomUserDetailsMapper extends LdapUserDetailsMapper 
                                         implements UserDetailsContextMapper {
    ...
    @Override
    public UserDetails mapUserFromContext(DirContextOperations ctx,
            String username, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {

            UserDetails user = super.mapUserFromContext(ctx, username,
                updateAuthorities(username));
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem.
I solved it by using a new Authentication object

```
SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
Authentication auth = context.getAuthentication();

// Updated authorities in the new Authentication object. 
// The existing authentication only provides whats available from LDAP when LDAP is used.
Authentication newAuth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                                 auth.getPrincipal(),
                                 auth.getCredentials(),
                                 context.getAuthentication().getAuthorities());
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(newAuth);
Object obj = newAuth.getPrincipal();
```

I had a class that extends `LdapUserDetailsMapper`, that overrides `mapUserFromContext`, in which I updated the user with the new set of authorities